# pubnub removeListener doesn't trigger on useEffect return

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, pubnub

While opening a single chat works flawlessly, entering a chat, then leaving the chat screen and entering the chat again causes double messaging and the listener isn't being removed despite placing it on the return in useEffect
I've even tried the solution in this thread: [React Pubnub Chat. Message dublication or no message at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68408713/react-pubnub-chat-message-dublication-or-no-message-at-all)

Hopefully, you guys can help me identify the issue. thanks in advance!

```
 useEffect(() => {
   
    const listener = {
      message: (envelope: any) => {
        if (envelope) {
          const message = {
            channel: envelope.channel,
            message: {
              ...envelope.message,
            },
            uuid: envelope.publisher,
            timetoken: envelope.timetoken,
          }

          dispatch(setMessage(message))
// this log activates the same amount of times you entered and left the chat, because the listener isn't being removed
          console.log('Message listener activated!') 
        }

        //   setLastTimeToken(message.timetoken)
      },
    }

    pubnub.addListener(listener)
    pubnub.setUUID(employer._id)


    pubnub.fetchMessages(
      {
        channels: [ch],
        count: 100,
      },
      (status, response) => {
        if (response.channels[ch]) {
          dispatch(setMessages(response?.channels[ch]))
        } else {
          dispatch(setMessages([]))
        }
      },
    )
    pubnub.subscribe({ channels: [ch] })

    const usersInfo = channel.split('_')
    if (channel != employer._id && usersInfo[1] !== 'job') {
      const deeberId = usersInfo[0]
      getCandidateById(deeberId).then(res => {
        dispatch(setSelectedChatCandidate(res))
      })
    }
    renderDisplayName()

    return () => {
      pubnub.removeListener(listener) 

      pubnub.unsubscribeAll()
    }

  }, [])
```

Comment: Have you added a `console.log` statement in the `return` to ensure it is getting called? Not sure why it wouldn't but just want to be sure it is happening.

Comment: Also, that last bit at the end, ` }, [])` (the dependencies of the `useEffect`), is empty. You might want to add `envelope.channel` to it so that is looks like this: `}, [envelope.channel])`. Might be unrelated to your issue but give it a try and you might need it either way. The other post you referenced does this. Actuall, that might be the root cause now that I think about it. The dependency will prevent `useEffect` from being invoked if a dependency has not changed. Give it a go and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Although it didn't fix my issue, I left it in just in case,
And I fixed the issue by not subscribing over and over, and just subscribing once in a channel's life.

Comment: If you are calling `pubnub.unsubscribeAll()` in the effects cleanup function, then you shouldn't have an issue with calling subscribe. However, there maybe some race condition occuring but I am not sure. Have you tried to call `pubnub.unsubscribe({ channels: [ch] })` instead?

Comment: @danlicky - you should post your solution as the answer to your question. I should give you some more SO rep ;)

Comment: @CraigConover 
Okay so , the truth is It did not fix my issue!, but the good news is:
I used pubnub v4.33 and the bug I was having was fixed by upgrading pubnub to 4.34.2. 
I found a solved issue in the github repo which was the exact same issue as I was having and it was fixed in the later update.
That was all that fixed my listeners being created every time I subscribe.
Thanks a lot for the time and your comments, it definitely improved some things with my code.

Comment: Oh awesome. I assume it is this fix: _"Fix listener callback is invoked multiple times."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the PubNub JS SDK fixed an issue that caused multiple callback triggering.
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/changelog#uv4342u